# Does each pod/container in a Kubernetes cluster has a different external ip?

Tags: networking, containers, kubernetes, distributed-computing

I created a cluster using Kubernetes and I want to make petitions to a server using different IP, does each of the nodes has a different one so that I can parallelize the requests? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to make calls to your pods you should use kubernetes services which effectively loadbalance requests between your pods, so that you do not need to worry about particular IPs of PODs at all.

That said, each pod has it's unique IP address, but these are internal addresses, in most implementations they come from the overlay network and are, in a way, internal to kube cluster (can't be directly called from outside - which is not exactly the full truth, but close enough).

Depending on your goals, Ingress might be interesting for you.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Comment: Each pod has its own internal address but there is only one external ip?

Comment: that really depends very much on the actual setup. You have separate inter-pod network that normally is visible only to pods. There is no external IP whatsoever to reach them. Every node in cluster has it's own IP though, which is also in many cases internal IP of the server-to-server network, yet it can be public (or there can be a public IP mapped to it) if node is exposed to the external world. But you need to remember that this is only the IP of the node. Now, if you use NodePort or LoadBalancer services, your node IP will have some ports open to direct to that service.